# What is the right way to say "Smb. was/is understood by smb."?

Tags: word-usage, construction

What is the right way to say "Smb. was/is understood by smb."? I suppose that this sentence is incorrect in English, so I'd like to know how to express this idea the right way.

E.g.:

> He understands me the right way. So...
>
> I am understood by him the right way. *(Sounds awful but how to say this in English)*

Is there any passive voice construction to express that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the passive structure correct. Modifying your example sentences:

> He **is understood by** me *in* the right way.
>
> I **am understood by** him *in* the right way.

The italicised *in* is more grammatically correct, but in conversational English omitting it is often fine.